# $f(x)=\cos x-x$. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|f(a_{n})|=0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, recursion

Here, we have a very well-known function $f(x)=\cos x-x$.

I know there is only one solution for $f(x)=0$.

Let it be $a\approx 0.739$.

Now, I'm trying to prove that if we have $a_{n+1}=\cos a_{n}$ for all $n$, then $a_{n}$ converges to $a$. (Just with MVT)

As a result, I got the fact "$\left | a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} \right |\leq \left | a_{n+1}-a_{n} \right |$ for all $n$."

So, I broke it into two cases s.t $\square $:"$\left | a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} \right |<  \left | a_{n+1}-a_{n} \right |$ for any $n$," and $\bigcirc $:"$\left | a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} \right |=   \left | a_{n+1}-a_{n} \right |$ for any $n$."

In case $\square $, we can get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|f(a_{n})|=0$.

But, I'm not certain if it is safe to say that "since $f(x)=0$ has a unique solution $x=a$, we have $\lim a_{n}=a$"

So, here's my general question: For any continuous & differentiable function $f(x)$ that has a unique solution $x=a$ for $f(x)=0$, if  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }|f(a_{n})|=0$, then is $\lim a_{n}=a$?

Comment: You need $f^{-1}$ to be continuous and then just use the properties that a continuous function maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences. I cannot find a counterexample right now but you should be able to.

Comment: If $a$ is an [attracting fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)#Attractive_fixed_points) then yes. If $f$ is a [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) then also yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. let $f(x)=xe^{x}$ Then $f(x)=0$ iff $x=0%$. But $f(-n) \to 0$ and $-n$ does not tend to $0$.